# Why laravel Stop Showing changes After sometime, I have to Delete cache file again and again,Any Solution

Tags: php, laravel, wampserver

hello i am using window 7 and i am using wampserver 3.1, Laravel stopped showing chnages after approx 10 min, so i have to delete cache manually again and again which is annoying, Any solution for this

Comment: Maybe if you would turn off caching in development phase?

Comment: make the cache forder read-only